# Set Global Maximum Precision

Tags: options, arbitrary-precision, machine-precision

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I've looked around and can't figure it out:

How do I set a global maximum precision for a notebook (or in general, globally)?

I have a large notebook in which I'm trying to get Mathematica to do all computations to a precision of 15 digits. The objective is to compare the results of the computation at the end with the default precision to the 15 I am enforcing. What are the options that I have to set at the beginning of the notebook to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Look up `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision`.

Comment: Bear in mind that *Mathematica*'s concept of precision is rather different to that of e.g. Maple, and there is in fact no "default precision". Numbers in *Mathematica* are either machine precision (53 bits, no precision tracking) or arbitrary precision with a specified number of digits and significance arithmetic enabled. If you want to work at fixed precision you must use `$MinPrecision = $MaxPrecision = prec` and always use arbitrary-precision numbers (machine precision ones will poison the calculation, so avoid introducing them at all).